# Exclude some patterns or binary files using sed / awk

Tags: sed, awk

I have patterns in a file something like this

```
parent/child
parent/child/child2
neighbor/child
neighbor/child/child3
```

I want to exclude all `neighbor` and its child using only sed and awk.

Output should be:

```
parent/child
parent/child/child2
```

Comment: **child** may be some binary files as well I want exclude them as well

Comment: What do you mean by 'binary file'? Is your input a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat a
parent/child
parent/child/child2
neighbor/child
neighbor/child/child3
$ sed '/neighbor/d' a
parent/child
parent/child/child2
```

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Common-Commands.html#Common-Commands):

> d - Delete the pattern space; immediately start next cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Use grep :

```
$ grep -v 'neighbor' file
parent/child
parent/child/child2
```

Comment: Thankx but, what if I'm only allowed to use sed or awk  not grep.

Comment: @Akinza That would not make sense? Maybe you want to change the search string to `'^neighbor'` to only search from the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

In Awk,

```
awk '{ if($0 !~ /^neighbor.*/) { print $0} }' file
```

Comment: What about `awk -F'/' '$1!="neighbor" { print }' file`